# Blobs are not allowed in this expression

Tags: sql, blob, informix

I face the following problem:

> *-615: Blobs are not allowed in this expression.*

```
SELECT ser
      ,task_code
      ,trans_serial
      ,trans_year
      ,CASE when nvl(length(signed_content), 0) <> '' THEN  signed_content  ELSE  attach_content  END AS signed_content
      ,CASE WHEN nvl(length(signed_content), 0) <> '' THEN 'signed_content' ELSE 'attach_content' END AS comes_from
FROM attach_detail
WHERE serial = 5 AND task_code = 88 AND trans_year = 2012 AND trans_serial = 23728
```

---

Note: `signed_content`, `attach_content` are of type `BYTE`; the other columns are of type `INT`.

Comment: Could you show the defition of the `attach_detail` table?

Comment: have you got the same error if you run select nvl(length(signed_content),0) from attach_detail ?

Comment: but this get the length not the data

Comment: how about :  select CASE when nvl(length(signed_content), 0) <> 0 THEN  signed_content  ELSE  attach_content  END AS signed_content from attach_detail ?

Comment: Are you sure you really want to compare the result of `nvl(NULL, 0)` against an empty string, instead of `0`?

Comment: This seems like a rather silly restriction.  The expanded error message for -615 from `finderr -615` doesn't cover the actual scenario at all.  I've created a 'feature request' bug for this (CQ idsdb00247982), but I'm not able to predict whether it will be fixed, much less when.

Comment: FYI: If you use CLOB (or BLOB) blobs instead of TEXT (or BYTE) blobs, then you can use them in UNIONs etc.  You can apply NULLIF or NVL to them.  You can't, however, use LENGTH on a CLOB.  Groan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that Informix does not allow blobs inside `CASE` expressions.

To work around this, you could transform the `CASE` into two subqueries:

```
SELECT ser
      ,task_code
      ,trans_serial
      ,trans_year
      ,signed_content AS signed_content
      ,'signed_content' AS comes_from
FROM attach_detail
WHERE nvl(length(signed_content), 0) <> ''
  AND serial = 5 AND task_code = 88 AND trans_year = 2012 AND trans_serial = 23728
UNION ALL
SELECT ser
      ,task_code
      ,trans_serial
      ,trans_year
      ,attach_content AS signed_content
      ,'attach_content' AS comes_from
FROM attach_detail
WHERE nvl(length(signed_content), 0) = ''
  AND serial = 5 AND task_code = 88 AND trans_year = 2012 AND trans_serial = 23728
```